# Instanciate UIElement from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

What I'm trying to achieve doesn't sounds like rocket science. What I'm trying to create is a custom control to which I could pass a list of UIElements items directly from XAML so each element could be different and embed different objects (grid / textbox / panel etc ... ).

Here is the xaml code I would like to use:

```
    <wpf:TileListDoubleItem>
        <wpf:TileListDoubleItem.FrontItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri,Verdana" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </wpf:TileListDoubleItem.FrontItem>
        <wpf:TileListDoubleItem.BackItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri,Verdana" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="World"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>                                 
        </wpf:TileListDoubleItem.BackItem>
    </wpf:TileListDoubleItem>
```

And here is my custom control code:

```
    public partial class TileListDoubleItem : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _flipped;
        internal bool CanFlip { get { return true; } }

        private bool flipped
        {
            get {
                return this._flipped;
            }
            set {
                this._flipped = value;
                DisplayItem = this._flipped ? BackItem : FrontItem;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TileSide> Sides { get; set; }
        public ICommand FlipCommand;

        public TileListDoubleItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FlipCommand = new FlipCommand(this);
            flipped = false;
        }

        private UIElement displayItem { get; set; }
        public UIElement DisplayItem
        {
            get { return this.displayItem; }
            set {
                if (this.displayItem != value)
                {
                    this.displayItem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DisplayItem");
                }
            }
        }

        public void Flip()
        {
            try
            {
                flipped = !flipped;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public UIElement FrontItem
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(FrontItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FrontItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FrontItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FrontItem", typeof(UIElement), typeof(TileListDoubleItem), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        public UIElement BackItem
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(BackItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackItem", typeof(UIElement), typeof(TileListDoubleItem), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this, both my FrontItem and BackItem are equal to null and are never set to the UIElement (Grid in this example).
I guess what I'm missing must be very obvious to some people.

Thanks in advance for anyone's help here.

Comment: When you say the property values are null, did you check that in the control's constructor? Both properties get their values set after the constructor was called. Besides that, it isn't clear what the control is supposed to do with them. None of them and also not the DisplayItem seem to be used as Content of your UserControl. It is also strange that you implement INotifyPropertyChanged for DisplayItem. It should instead be another dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

Your properies are set as expected. You can confirm this by for example create two `TextBlocks` that binds to the properties of your control:

```
<wpf:TileListDoubleItem x:Name="control">
    <wpf:TileListDoubleItem.FrontItem>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri,Verdana" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </wpf:TileListDoubleItem.FrontItem>
    <wpf:TileListDoubleItem.BackItem>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontFamily="Calibri,Verdana" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="World"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </wpf:TileListDoubleItem.BackItem>
</wpf:TileListDoubleItem>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding FrontItem.Children[0].Text, ElementName=control}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding BackItem.Children[0].Text, ElementName=control}" />
```

Obviously the properties won't be set by the time the constructor of `TileListDoubleItem` returns. The XAML parser needs to instantiate the object before it can set any of its properties, just like you do when you create an instance of a class yourself.

Comment: @Chris? Did you try this or what happened?